# Looking for a single word that means "I am redoing the typesetting of this document"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been using the word "retypeset" or rather "I am retypesetting this document", but I cannot seem to find those words listed in the dictionary.  I am wondering if they should be written with a hyphen, as in "re-typeset" or "re-typesetting", or if there is another word that would carry the same meaning.

Sample sentence:
"I am redoing the typesetting of this document in a larger font so that it will be easier to read."

Comment: I am *reformatting* this document, perhaps.

Comment: I like 'reformatting' also. I feel like it's a term that people often use and can easily understand.

Comment: @Dan - `reformatting` is perfect for the context. Can't believe that didn't come to mind. If you added it as an answer I could actually upvote it.

Comment: restyling perhaps?

Comment: Traditionally, this would be expressed as "resetting the type".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Re--* is such a common prefix that you can often get away with using it even when the compound isn't in the dictionary. That's especially true here as *retype* is common; in fact if it wasn't, I'd suggest hyphenating but I don't.

Your sample also could easily work with "... I'm typesetting the document *again* in a larger font..."

---

Another word formed with *re--* is *reformatting*.  This turned out to be suitable here.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer, but as I liked `reformatting` better, that is the word I ended up using and so I am not marking this as the answer. I wish @Dan would add it so I could select that.

Comment: In the end, I decided to mark this as an answer so that the question is no longer open and I didn't want to "answer my own question." I did end up using the word reformatting, but as your answer is helpful and informative - have some point nuts.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll add *reformatting* as a footnote for the archives